# how can I detect optic disc from retinal image using opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on detect optic disc from retinal images, by using OpenCV-python

I processed image with these procedures.

1) resize the image. (original size is more than 2000 x 2000)

2) convert to grayscale

3) edge detection with canny.

4) apply gaussianblur.

and the result is this
processed_image

[image]

I don't know how to detect optic disc with this result.

How can I detect optic disc with this?

or Am I approached the wrong direction?

Comment: This alone will not work. You could try working on a different color space where the bright regions are more highlighted like HSV

Comment: Did you try anything else?

Comment: Yes. I tried with your advise and I got some progress. I located brightest spot but inaccurate with several images that have similar brightness spot in other location. So I will try with SVM but I don't know it going well. Thanks for your advise! @JeruLuke

Comment: Great !!! You can also work with Haar classifier, I did the same thing and was able to locate the optic disc nearly in 90% of all cases. If the image is clean with no blurriness Haar would work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can try blob detection using opencv. there is a function in opencv called HoughCircles()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please provide some source code to support the given answer explaining show how it solves the problem.